# MERN project Deployment

Tags: heroku, deployment, cloud, mern, web-hosting

Is there any platform where I can deploy my web-app free & without providing PayPal or any other payment credentials ?

I tried using Heroku, but it requires payment credentials. Please let me know if there is any website or platform where I can deploy my project without any payment credentials.